# How to define base class and generic constraint

Tags: c#, generics

I want to define a class **ServiceAccessBase** as implementing an interface **IServiceAccessBase** and using generic type **TResult**. The generic type should also have a constraint.

How should I do that?

This doesn't compile:

```
public class ServiceAccessBase<TResult> : IServiceAccessBase
             where TResult : TResultBase, class, new
{}
```

Comment: The `class` constraint must be placed before any other constraint, and the `new` constraint (correctly placed at the end) should be `new()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ServiceAccessBase<TResult, TResultBase> : IServiceAccessBase
             where TResult : class, TResultBase, new()
{ }
```